# Rate limit feature is not working in nestjs app

Tags: node.js, nestjs, rate-limiting

I'm exploring the **NestJS** and I'm trying to explore `rate limit` feature.

This is my `main.ts` file.

```
import { NestFactory } from '@nestjs/core';
import { AppModule } from './app.module';
import * as rateLimit from 'express-rate-limit';
async function bootstrap() {
  const app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule);
  await app.listen(3000);
  app.use(
    rateLimit({
      windowMs: 60 * 1000, // 1 minutes
      max: 10, // limit each IP to 100 requests per windowMs
    }),
  );
}
bootstrap();
```

I'm using its official site for [reference](https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/security).

**Required output**

- User should not able to call API/access app more than 10 times in each minute.

**Note:**

- I'm using `jmeter` to test API call.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to set the use of rateLimit before you call `app.listen()`. Once you call `app.listen()` you can't assign more middleware to be used for the server.

Comment: Ohhh sorry, That's my bad. Thanks for your answer. It works for me. I really appreciate it.